# Syntax Error when Assigning URL to sys.argv[1]

Tags: python

I am trying to request a URL which contains a grid of numbers:

```
import sys
import urllib.request
"url" = sys.argv[1]
f = urllib.request.urlopen("url")
for line in f
    print(line)
f.close()
```

Each time I run this program it returns error can't assign to string literal for sys.argv[1]. Not sure if there is some package that needs to be installed for it to not be an error, or if I am making some other mistake.

Comment: The message tells you the problem - no package is going to make `"url" = ...` make sense, you need a _name_ as the target for assignment not a _value_.

Comment: Mistakes like this are natural when learning Python, but it's also a sign you *urgently* need a better Python reference to start from.

Comment: Gotcha, I just started learning about three or four weeks ago, forgot to add for loop colon. I also had an actual url in for url but took it out for privacy reasons, it is not an actual variable, but a file path(?).

Answer (score 1):

`"url" = ...` is invalid syntax. It never is accepted, no matter the package. It should look like `url = ...`. When you use the variable, also remember to remove the quotes around it.

Also, you are missing a colon (`:`) in your for loop line.

Here is the full code:

```py
import sys
import urllib.request

url = sys.argv[1] # remove quotes around variable name ("")
f = urllib.request.urlopen(url) # remove quotes around variable call ("")
for line in f: # add colon (:)
    print(line)
f.close()
```